# getting data from callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, graphql

i am wondering about the best way to get  token variable back  to the higher order function scope >> so i can return it from the higher order function

```
signinUser: async (_, data) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({'email': data.email.email}).exec();

  console.log(bcrypt.compare(data.email.password,user.password, (err,result)=>{
    if(err){return("sorry error")}
    if(result) {
      var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id},
                           config.secret, {expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7});
    }
  }))

  return {user: {id: user._id, name: user.name, email: user.email}, token: "this is a token"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with the async await syntax, you need to pass the  bcrypt.compare call to a promise with Q or BlueBird libraries and write code like this:

```
let result = await Q.nfcall(bcrypt.compare, data.email.password,user.password)
if(result) {
    var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id},
                       config.secret, {expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7});
}

return {id: user._id, name: user.name, email: user.email}, token: token}
```